# How to link 32 bit shared library (.so file) to 32 bit executable?

Tags: shared-library, 32bit

## Short question

I tried to use `gcc -m32 -c file.c -o file.o -Llib -llibname` command to link my 32 bit shared library (`.so` file) to 32 bit executable. But it seems like library not added.

## Long question

I making 32 bit kernel and now, I made a library for my kernel and I want to link my library to my kernel.

I tried to use `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -c kernel/kernel.c -o kernel/kernel.o -Llib -lkernel` command. But it seems like library not added.

(`kernel/kernel.c` is my kernel C file and `lib/libkernel.so` is my library `.so` file. I made my `.so` file using `gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fPIC -shared lib/libkernel/printf.c -o lib/libkernel.so` command.)

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: "it's not working" is not a useful problem description.  What is "not working"?  What is happening?  What output do you expect to see?  What output are you actually getting?  If your car doesn't run, do you tell the mechanic "It's not working" and then walk away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must create static library (e.g. `ar rcs libname.a lib.o`) and link it (e.g. `ld -melf_i386 -Llib -lname`).